# In Azure App Services, why can't I access my tables after a succesful logon (using App Service authentication service)?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

According to the stream on Azure, this section of code results in a successful login:

```
    MobileServiceUser user = null;
    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        string message;
        bool success = false;


        var provider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory;

        // Use the PasswordVault to securely store and access credentials.
        PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
        PasswordCredential credential = null;

        try
        {
            // Try to get an existing credential from the vault.
            credential = vault.FindAllByResource(provider.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // When there is no matching resource an error occurs, which we ignore.
        }

        if (credential != null)
        {
            // Create a user from the stored credentials.
            user = new MobileServiceUser(credential.UserName);
            credential.RetrievePassword();
            user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = credential.Password;

            // Set the user from the stored credentials.
            App.MobileService.CurrentUser = user;

            // Consider adding a check to determine if the token is 
            // expired, as shown in this post: http://aka.ms/jww5vp.

            success = true;
            message = string.Format("Cached credentials for user - {0}", user.UserId);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Login with the identity provider.
                user = await App.MobileService
                    .LoginAsync(provider, true);

                // Create and store the user credentials.
                credential = new PasswordCredential(provider.ToString(),
                    user.UserId, user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
                vault.Add(credential);

                success = true;
                message = string.Format("You are now logged in - {0}", user.UserId);
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException)
            {
                message = "You must log in. Login Required";
            }
        }

        var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();

        return success;
    }
```

But when I try to grab information from an IServiceTable, access is denied. I did notice that in the stream from Azure, that the logon method that is used in the attempt to access the table is "anonymous." Can anyone help? (I have examined the token, and it looks right.)

```
    public IMobileServiceTable<Finding> FindingsTable { get {return findingsTable;} }
    private IMobileServiceTable<Finding> findingsTable;

    private MobileServiceClient client;

    public ClientAPI(string url)
    {
        //client = new MobileServiceClient(url);
        client = App.MobileService;
        findingsTable = client.GetTable<Finding>();
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Finding>> GetAllFindingsAsync()
    {
     // The line below triggers the no access error:   
        var findings = await findingsTable.Select(f => f).ToCollectionAsync();
```

Here is a graphic showing the token that is sent to the service when attempting to access the table:

[image: Link to screenshot of token]

Answer (score 0):

The `nbf` from your `authenticationToken` represents `GMT: Thursday, December 21, 2017 9:56:15 PM`, but the `exp` represents `GMT: Saturday, January 20, 2018 9:56:15 PM`. AFAIK, the valid `exp` is an hour larger that `nbf` by default.

I would recommend you disable the caching tokens and directly call `App.MobileService.LoginAsync` for logging, then leverage the [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces and try to access your online table `Finding` to narrow this issue.

Also, you could access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad` for logging via the browser and retrieve the `authenticationToken`, then you could decode your token and compare it with your local caching token. After logged via the browser, you could access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}` to retrieve your table records to narrow this issue. Additionally, for caching tokens, you could follow adrian hall's book about [Caching Tokens](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/#caching-tokens).

Comment: Thanks. I've taken your advice and commented out the lines that control token caching.  Unfortunately, even with manually sending the token in a request via Postman, I still get access denied. I do get redirected to the successful logon page. Any chance my error could be caused by my entries in redirect URI or other settings on Azure?  I've checked and rechecked them, but I maybe I'm not understanding something.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: For postman, you could get `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}` and add a **x-zumo-auth** header with the value set to the `authenticationToken`. Moreover, you could try to configure the other login provider (e.g. MSA, Facebook,etc.), then directly access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{microsoftaccount|facebook}` for logging, then access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}` via the browser to make sure your mobile server-side could be successfully accessed, then check your mobile client code.